# jquery accordion close first header on click and open second header, and vice versa

Tags: html, jquery-ui, accordion

Im quite new to JQuery. Have one question about Jquery accordion. Is it possible (having 2 panels) to close first panel and automatically open second by clicking on header of first panel and then again clicking (on the same first header) to close second panel and open first one?

I found something similar in Doug Neiner answer :

[Trigger jquery accordion menu by an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027040/trigger-jquery-accordion-menu-by-an-event)

but it doesn't seem to work in my case. (But I checked it on button and it was fine). This is altered code but when I click first panel header when its closed, first panel open and instantly closing:

**JQUERY**

```
$("#first_panel").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var acc   = $("#myaccordion"),
      index = acc.accordion('option','active'),
      total = 2 ,
      nxt   = index + 1;

  if (nxt >= total) {
  nxt = 0; // Loop around to the first item
  }

  acc.accordion('activate', nxt);
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="myaccordion">

  <h3 id="first_panel">FIRST PANEL</h3>
<div>
 Text...
</div>

  <h3 id="second_panel">SECOND PANEL</h3>
<div>
 More text...
</div>

</div>
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Mn2L4/

Comment: This would be fairly easy to do simply by checking where the active class is on click. Give it a try and report back.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply, I was working on that, and in the meantime Zeaklous wrote a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default event for the accordion

`$("#myaccordion").accordion({event: false});`

[See the updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Mn2L4/1/)

Comment: Ok, that works great, thanks very much! At first I thought it has something to do with default event but had no idea how to prevent it.